# History back for ajax

Tags: ajax

Is there a way to go back in history only for ajax calls ?

I'm looking for a history back button that only works for ajax calls on the current page.
So the button should not have the power to leave the page as we know it from browser back button.

Comment: *"So the button should not have the power to leave the page as we know it from browser back button"* you can't prevent that, but the rest of your request, sure, but you'll have to build it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) for this.

Basically what you are doing is calling `history.pushState()` when doing an AJAX call and listening for the `popstate` event on the `window` object. But the logic that will manipulate your DOM to show the last state will have to be implemented by yourself.